# How to detect if user has reach a waypoint with HERE SDK?

Tags: android, here-api

I'm using HERE android premium SDK.
App is generating a route with multiple waypoint, and start the navigation process.
I'm trying to find a way to detect each time a user has stop or pass through a route defined waypoint (defined as a stop point).
Is there a procedure for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NavigationManager#ManeuverEventListener` to listen for maneuver updates, then use the `NavigationManager#getNextManeuver` and `NavigationManager#getAfterNextManeuver` APIs to check the upcoming `Maneuver`s. Then, you can use `Maneuver#getAction()` API to check if the `Action` is `STOPOVER`.

API Docs:

- [NavigationManager](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-guidance-navigationmanager.html)
- [Maneuver](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-premium/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-routing-maneuver.html)

Comment: Thanks Andrew.

This is how i implement this in my code.
I'm trying to link a specific waypoint to a Maneuver STOPOVER.
Is there a way to create an ID to each waypoint so i'll be able to detect which STOPOVER the driver has just reach?

Comment: In addition, please find the following link which explains why this approach can't be reliable:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836266/newinstructioneventlistener-skipping-some-stop-over-maneuvers

Comment: How close are your stopovers? Would it not be possible to tell by simply comparing how close the maneuver is to your stopover (for example, using `GeoCoordinate#distanceTo(GeoCoordinate coord)`) or a similar approach?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, your answer helped me too :-) Maybe do you know how to detect a waypoint of type PASS_THROUGH?

Answer (score 0):

How I do/did it?

A combination of onStopoverReached(int index) and a dummy Passthrough as a Stopover.

1. Set your RoutePlan with the Passthrough waypoint and a dummy stopover waypoint of the same credentials as the Passthrough waypoint.
2. Call the NavigationEventManager's onStopoverReached method to tell you when the dummy Passthrough stopover has been reached or passed.

Other thing to note...

1. A ReRoute listener will never return a Passthrough Waypoint so...
2. You can use the reRouteEnd method to reinsert a Passthrough Waypoint in a new RoutePlan along with the Stopover Waypoints returned by reRouteEnd's RouteResult and recalculate a new route and of course pickup a fresh RouteResult at the Router listener's onCalculateRouteFinished.